# The Monge- Ampère equation with a non positive right hand side

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a domain, $u$ and $f$ are real valued functions on $\Omega$, $(u_{ij})$ is the Hessian matrix of $u$. The function $f$ may change sign: that said, do there exist solutions for the following equation?
$$
\det u_{ij}=f
$$

Answer (score 1):

In general nothing is known. Only local solvability is known for some special cases.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me some references?

Comment: The first page of this paper summarizes what little is known in the 2-dimensional case. Some of this can be extended to higher dimensions.

Comment: Sorry, Could you give me the  title of this paper?

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's the link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2241. Another one is https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6704

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!